# Angular with Webpack - loadChildren can't find the module

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, lazy-loading

I'm trying load an admin I bought that works with Angular4, however I'm having some trouble configuring the project to run with Webpack:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    "path": "",
    "component": ThemeComponent,
    "canActivate": [AuthGuard],
    "children": [
        {
            "path": "index",
            "loadChildren": './pages/default/index/index.module#IndexModule'
        }
    ],
    {
        "path": "**",
        "redirectTo": "404",
        "pathMatch": "full"
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class ThemeRoutingModule {}
```

when I run the app, I get this message in console:

> NavigationError {id: 1, url: "/", error: Error: Cannot find module
>   './pages/default/index/index.module'. at eval (eval at
>   ./src/main/weba…} error : Error: Cannot find module
>   './pages/default/index/index.module'. at eval (eval at
>   ./src/main/webapp/admin/app lazy recursive
>   (http://localhost:8080/admin/app/main.bundle.js:6:1), :5:9)
>   at ZoneDelegate.invoke
>   (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:391:26) at
>   Object.onInvoke
>   (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js:4094:33)
>   at ZoneDelegate.invoke
>   (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:390:32) at
>   Zone.run
>   (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:141:43) at
>   eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:831:57)
>   at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:424:31) at
>   Object.onInvokeTask
>   (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js:4085:33)
>   at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:423:36) at
>   Zone.runTask
>   (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:191:47) id :
>   1 url : "/"

I know the path to the module is correct, as I can import this module without problem in the same file:

```
import {IndexModule} from './pages/default/index/index.module';
```

My Webpack config is using this to proccess the typescript:

```
module: {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.ts$/,
        enforce: 'pre',
        loaders: 'tslint-loader',
        exclude: ['node_modules', new RegExp('reflect-metadata\\' + path.sep + 'Reflect\\.ts')]
    },
    {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loaders: [
            'awesome-typescript-loader',
            'angular-router-loader?debug=true',
            'angular2-template-loader'
        ]
    }
```

[image: project structure]

Is there something wrong I'm doing I didn't notice?

Comment: You need something like this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-router-loader

Comment: did you happen to find the answer for this ?

Comment: hi @brevleq. did you get ans for this? If yes, kindly update here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of import using module path, I discovered I can import using function. This way it worked:

```
{
    "path": "index",
    "loadChildren": () => IndexModule
}
```

Comment: But this is not lazy loading. Is there a solution to still use loadChildren as a string?

Answer (score 0):

The location of your lazy-loaded modules should start at the `app` folder.
 Try to add the `app` keyword to your string like this

```
loadChildren: 'app/theme/pages/default/index/index.module#IndexModule'},
```

Also I think you are missing a curly brace here

```
{
    "path": "",
    "component": ThemeComponent,
    "canActivate": [AuthGuard],
    "children": [
        {
            "path": "index",
             loadChildren: 'app/theme/pages/default/index/index.module#IndexModule'},\

        }
    ]
} <-------- ,
```

Comment: can you show the path  to your indexModule from the app folder?

Comment: added a print of the path

Comment: of course it will not work! I just give you the idea to fix it. well i'll update my answer :)

Comment: yes, I've already tried use full path: NavigationError {id: 1, url: "/", error: Error: Cannot find module 'app/theme/pages/default/index/index.module'

Comment: Don't use the indexmodule inside the children. Move it to its own path

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155794/discussion-between-brevleq-and-brijmcq).

Answer (score -1):

If you're using webpack, you need the [angular-router-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-router-loader):

```
loaders: [
  {
    test: /\.ts$/,
    loaders: [
      'awesome-typescript-loader',
      'angular-router-loader'
    ]
  }
]
```

Create a module which loads additional routes:

```
const routeModule:ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(routes);
@NgModule({
    imports:      [ routeModule ],
    declarations: [ ... ]
})
export class InboxModule{ }
```

Create your routes and reference the lazy-loaded module  (the path is relative):

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';

export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'index', loadChildren: './theme/pages/default/index/index.module#IndexModule' }
];
```

Comment: the path to IndexModule is relative to AppModule, are you sure the path is correct? Try adding the 'theme' to the path like my example...